# How to open a cmd from a c# forms application, that accepts input

Tags: c#, forms, compiler-construction, process, cmd

I am writing a compiler in c# for school and I wanted to add a graphical user interface to it so that I can choose which file to compile and run, and then i want the program to run in the cmd just like regular compilers ie. Visual studio run your app.

The compiler runs the compiled program in an interpreter so if the interpreter asks for input then i need a way for the user to be able to enter input and i dont want to open a modal window a ton of times for input and output. instead I would like to open the cmd and run the program while my forms app runs separately.

Comment: You're not going to get very far just asking for someone to tell you what to do. Do you know where you need to start? Have you got any code? You need to show effort before people are going to help

Comment: @user708774, Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [C# Process.Start](http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start) to startup new process from you application.

For Example.

```
 static void Main()
    {
    // A.
    // Open specified Word file.
    OpenMicrosoftWord(@"C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Gears.docx");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Open specified word document.
    /// </summary>
    static void OpenMicrosoftWord(string f)
    {
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = "WINWORD.EXE";
    startInfo.Arguments = f;
    Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
```